# RHEL 7 screensaver commands equivalent to RHEL 6

Tags: gnome, screensaver

On RHEL 6, the following command will display screensaver commands:

```
man gnome-screensaver-command
```

- -q, --query
  Query the state of the screensaver
- -l, --lock
  Tells the running screensaver process to lock the screen immediately
- -a, --activate
  Turn the screensaver on (blank the screen)
- -d, --deactivate
  If the screensaver is active then deactivate it (un-blank the screen)
- -i, --inhibit
  Inhibit the screensaver from activating. Command blocks while inhibit is active.

I am having a difficult time finding this command on RHEL 7; when I run `gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.screensaver` I get a list of commands, but I don't know which of those those are equivalent to the above commands:

- picture-opacity
- logout-enabled
- lock-enabled
- logout-delay
- embedded-keyboard-enabled
- primary-color
- idle-activation-enabled
- secondary-color
- logout-command
- color-shading-type
- embedded-keyboard-command
- show-notifications
- lock-delay
- status-message-enabled
- ubuntu-lock-on-suspend